# JList click one and put it into first JTextfield then click another into next JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlist

I'm currently creating a soundboard like application where the person is going to click one of the items in my `JList` and its going to set the name of the next available text field as what was just clicked.

For example, my `JList` contains `hello, testing1, testing2`. If `testing2` is clicked first I would like to put it into the first textfield, and if `hello` is clicked next I'd like to put it into the 2nd textfield and so on.

The program will have around 100 items in the JList by the time the app is done. I currently can not get this to work and have tried countless times.

Also there is a problem that when the top one and a different `JList` item is clicked the top one will display first. Not necessarily a problem if I can get the problem fully functional but it makes it feel a little wonky.

My code so far:

```
package com.leagueoflegends.soundboard;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import java.awt.*;

public class Soundboard implements ListSelectionListener {

static JList<Object> list;
String[] text = { "hello", "testing1", "testing2" };
Icon icon;
JLabel pictureLabel;
JPanel insidePanel;
JTextField inlineText;

JTextField field[] = new JTextField[6];

public Soundboard() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("soundboard!");

    JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    //icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Tray.png"));
    //pictureLabel = new JLabel(icon);

    list = new JList<Object>(text); // data has type Object[]
    list.setSelectionModel(new DefaultListSelectionModel(){
        public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1){
            if(super.isSelectedIndex(index0)){
                super.removeSelectionInterval(index0,index1);
            }else{
                super.addSelectionInterval(index0,index1);
            }
        }
    });
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);

    JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
    listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    listScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 60));
    // listScroller.setSize(new Dimension(250, 60));

    JPanel smallPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 3));
    // smallPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        insidePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        insidePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        field[i] = new JTextField();
        field[i].setEditable(false);
        field[i].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        insidePanel.add(field[i], BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        smallPanel.add(insidePanel);

    }

    masterPanel.add(smallPanel);
//  masterPanel.add(pictureLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    masterPanel.add(listScroller, BorderLayout.WEST);
    f.add(masterPanel);

    f.pack();
    f.setSize(1000, 800);
    f.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 350));
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (list.getSelectedIndex() == i) {
                field[0].setText(text[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                    | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new Soundboard();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be to;

1. Create an array or `List` of your `JTextField`s.  Add these your UI.
2. Create a counter, indicating the current "empty" field
3. Use either a `MouseListener` or `ListSelectionListener` to identify when the user has selected something, extract the value from the list.  Using the "current" counter, extract the `JTextField` from the `List` and set it's value accordingly, increment the counter